# Configuring OpenSSH for Windows in Cygwin - can't leave blank password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, cygwin, openssh

I install OpenSSH in Cygwin under Windows 7 to install Hadoop.

I had OpenSSH installed previously, but with a password. All attempts to remove password are failed, so I re-installed Cygwin. 
I want OpenSSH without password too and followed these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/tariqmislam/2159173).

However, it does not let me leave a password blank. 
Why is that and what should I do?

Additional info: I am running Cygwin bash with admin privileges. My Windows does not have a password set.

I see the following:

```
User@computer ~
$ chmod +r /etc/passwd

User@computer ~
$ chmod u+w /etc/passwd

User@computer ~
$ chmod +r /etc/group

User@computer ~
$ chmod u+w /etc/group

User@computer ~
$ chmod 755 /var

User@computer ~
$ touch /var/log/sshd.log

User@computer ~
$ chmod 664 /var/log/sshd.log

User@computer ~
$ ssh-host-config

*** Info: Generating /etc/ssh_host_key
*** Info: Generating /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
*** Info: Generating /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
*** Info: Generating /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
*** Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file
*** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file
*** Info: Privilege separation is set to yes by default since OpenSSH 3.3.
*** Info: However, this requires a non-privileged account called 'sshd'.
*** Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share/doc/openssh/READ            ME.privsep.
*** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) NO
*** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) no
*** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file

*** Query: Do you want to install sshd as a service?
*** Query: (Say "no" if it is already installed as a service) (yes/no) yes
*** Query: Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon: []
*** Info: On Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, and above, the
*** Info: SYSTEM account cannot setuid to other users -- a capability
*** Info: sshd requires.  You need to have or to create a privileged
*** Info: account.  This script will help you do so.

*** Info: You appear to be running Windows XP 64bit, Windows 2003 Server,
*** Info: or later.  On these systems, it's not possible to use the LocalSystem
*** Info: account for services that can change the user id without an
*** Info: explicit password (such as passwordless logins [e.g. public key
*** Info: authentication] via sshd).

*** Info: If you want to enable that functionality, it's required to create
*** Info: a new account with special privileges (unless a similar account
*** Info: already exists). This account is then used to run these special
*** Info: servers.

*** Info: Note that creating a new user requires that the current account
*** Info: have Administrator privileges itself.

*** Info: The following privileged accounts were found: 'cyg_server' .

*** Info: This script plans to use 'cyg_server'.
*** Info: 'cyg_server' will only be used by registered services.
*** Query: Do you want to use a different name? (yes/no) no
*** Query: Please enter the password for user 'cyg_server':
*** Query: Please enter the password for user 'cyg_server':
```

Comment: Not sure if I am misinterpreting your question but the `cyg_server` account is only the local account which sshd used for privilege separation. This is not the user you need to login with via `SSH`, you should be able to use any local user to login. Not sure though if `sshd` itself will allow empty passwords for authentication. In case you need automated authentication against `SSH` you could have a look at public key authentication which should also work with cygwin

Comment: I am referring to what I see in the instructions I followed. It worked for them: 14. Please enter the password for user 'cyg_server': <LEAVE BLANK, JUST HIT ENTER>
15. Reenter: <LEAVE BLANK, JUST HIT ENTER>

Comment: Do I have to create an Administrator account on my machine and use it?

Comment: Yes, but that is only the account used to execute the service itself. This has nothing todo with the account you use to login via ssh. You should be able to simply login with any local account on your machine.